# Possible issue with my W4 and tax return

Tags: united-states, income-tax

After I graduated high school I grabbed a minimum wage job ($10) and only worked for 3-4 months before the year ended. I ended up getting $440 back through federal and state tax refund. Then for the entire next year I worked minimum wage at a different job (still $10) with better future prospects and my boss gave me a $2 raise (now $12) in November if I remember correctly.

I'd been looking forward to my tax return because if working 3-4 months netted me almost $450 on my tax return then I should probably expect 3-4x more than that on this years tax return since I worked the whole year. Well long story short, I'm filing my taxes through TurboTax and it looks like federal and state combined is only giving me $200. I'm no tax expert and I'm not sure where to ask this but I'm wondering if my raise at the end of the year is causing TurboTax to miscalculate how much money I owe in taxes and therefore miscalculate how much I should be getting back?

No matter how I look at it I don't understand how I worked 3-4x as much as the previous year and paid 3-4x times more in taxes and am only receiving half as much on my tax return.

Comment: Note that the money you get back from the IRS is your tax REFUND.  Your tax RETURN is the paper or electronic forms you fill in and send to the IRS.

Comment: I very much appreciate this question because it represents some common misunderstandings about the complicated US tax system!  It's amazing what kind of weird system 400+ folks in a room together, re-elected every 2 years can come up with over the period of a century.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky that you don't *owe* additional tax. A refund is not a given, not some sort of government-sponsored annual bonus.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 The problem isn't them so much as it is TurboTax and similar companies that profit from the confusion. There have been some excellent laws proposed recently that would massively simplify tax preparation, but lobbying by tax preparation software companies (who would lose business if the process became easy enough that their software was no longer necessary) got it shut down every time.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: It's already easy enough that tax preparation software (beyond the IRS Free Fillable Forms) isn't necessary.  It's just that all the paid tax preparers have convinced people that it isn't.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 The European tax systems is much easier. How much did you make, now give it to us bureaucrats because we know best. :p

Comment: Expecting to get a larger tax refund because you made more money or worked more is not really sensible. In particular, the more you work the more accurate the withholding estimates are (since they assume you work all year) so the less extra you'll pay and thus you will get back less.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're receiving less back because the withholding calculations were more accurate.

If you hadn't received a raise, you would probably have gotten $0 back at filing time.

Because the US income tax isn't a flat percentage, but is progressive, the taxes owed during any paycheck require knowing your income for the rest of the year in order to figure out what bracket you're in, which together with your credits and deductions, determine your effective tax rate.  The rules for withholding are quite complicated, but an approximation that's good enough for our purposes is: "Assume you earn at the same rate for all 52 weeks, calculate the total income tax owed during the year, divide it back out by 52 weeks".

When you only worked 3-ish months, that rule overguessed your total tax bill and therefore took out too much from each check.  And you got the extra back at the end of the year, after Uncle Sam got to use it all year, without paying you any interest (yes, refunds are bad for the taxpayer!)  In addition, you qualified for the Earned Income Tax Credit, so **the total taxes you paid were likely negative**.

When you worked all year, withholding for the first 10 months was based on a full year of $10/hr (which slightly underestimated your actual tax due after figuring in the raise) and for the last 2 months was based on a full year of $12/hr (which overestimated your actual tax, because you didn't earn at that rate all year).  Additionally, not only did the EITC not increase by a factor of four the way your pay did, you lost it completely (assuming you are single with no children).

And assuming you correctly typed in the numbers from your W-2, TurboTax knows exactly how much you owe in taxes, because it knows your exact income, and the exact amount you already paid.  None of the withholding calculations during the year "knew" either how much you owed or how much you already paid, even the last paycheck of the year where all the information was available (because doing the accurate calculation wouldn't by allowed by the IRS)

By earning all year and at a higher rate, you had a higher effective tax rate.  No, it's not fair.  It's progressive.

Comment: "No, it's not fair. It's progressive" sounds like you're getting awfully close to some lines there.

Comment: @not_a_comcast_employee: That's weird, because I'm sure the question wording, when I answered it, complained about fairness.  But I can't find it anywhere in the history.  Perhaps I'm mixing thoughts in from a question I read right before. In any case, that statement is objectively correct, so unless there are some lines around uncomfortable facts, I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: It's perfectly fine as long as "progressive" means "progressive tax system" of course. I just wanted to point out, that it *almost* could mean "of course it's unfair, it's supported by the political left" which is not a statement that should be made here.

Comment: @not_a_comcast_employee: I do mean "progressive tax system".  I also know that's the only kind of tax system the political left is willing to support, but that as you say is off-topic, so why bring it up?

Comment: Overly simplified but if you make 100K and I make 50K, we both pay the same amount of tax on the first 50K of earnings.  Not sure what's unfair about that.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that it makes it sound like you are saying it is unfair because it is associated with the political left. The language could be improved.

Comment: I read "progressive" as referring to a progressive tax system, but I still think it detracts from the otherwise excellent answer. We can argue all day about whether regressive, progressive, flat, VAT, or any other plan is "fair." The OP didn't mention fairness (I checked the question edit history) so in my ever so humble opinion, this answer would be better if it didn't, either.

Comment: Saying that progressive taxes are "not fair" is a political opinion, and detracts from this otherwise useful answer.

Comment: Claiming that a flat tax is fair implies that $100 means to a person who makes $100,000 the same amount that $10 means to a person who makes $10,000, which isn't true. Money has **diminishing marginal value/returns** (just like how the first piece of halloween candy you eat is better than the last piece you eat), which is why progressive taxes make sense. Figuring out the progressive curve is difficult, so any specific progressive tax could be unfair, however a flat tax is guaranteed to be unfair.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Except the US income tax system doesn't work cumulatively like that.  OP got the Earned Income Tax Credit in 2017.  In 2018, he wouldn't, because his earned income is over the threshold.  And there are lots more traps like that one.

Comment: @BenVoigt You referred to the progressive tax system.  Tax credits are something else entirely i.e. not a tax.

Answer (score 9):

The calculation may very well be correct, because income taxes (federal and some states) are *progressive*, not flat. Your refund depends on your tax withholdings in relation to what you actually turn out to owe. For 2017, your total income was low enough that your tax owed was probably zero (the first ~$10k of income is excluded for singles), so you received all your withholdings back. For 2018, because you worked the whole year, your withholdings came close to matching your total tax owed (as they're designed to), so your refund is small.

If your W-2 is correct, the information you entered in TurboTax already properly accounts for your annual totals including the effect of the raise late in the year.

If you're lucky enough to earn more money over time, you'll have the privilege of paying higher and higher tax rates.

Answer (score 3):

The withholding tables are based on working at that rate all year.  There is a substantial base of income that is not taxed, so if you only work part of the year your withholding will be too high and you will get a large percentage of your witholding (maybe all of it) as a refund.  Now that you worked all year the withholding is more accurate so your refund is a lower part of the withholding.

I have heard the tables were adjusted to lower the withholding so people would see the tax "cut" in their paychecks, which would lower people's refunds.  I do not know if that is true.

Comment: It's not that the tables were done differently, it's that the tables over-withhold for those who itemize, and under the new rules, a lot fewer people itemize.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not according to this [announcement from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/2018-withholding-tables-now-available): "WASHINGTON — The Internal Revenue Service today released Notice 1036, which *updates the income-tax withholding tables* for 2018 reflecting changes made by the tax reform legislation enacted last month." [Emphasis mine]

Comment: @JimmyJames: The brackets changed, therefore the tables had to be updated.  But they follow the same formulas, just with different tax rates and different standard deductions.

Comment: @BenVoigt This seems like a distinction without a difference.  No one is claiming that they came up with a brand new system.  Just that the withholding was lower overall.

Comment: @JimmyJames: The answer says that there's a specific purpose for the update other.  Serving a new purpose would require changing the methodology, or at least the timing, of the update.  If the same old methodology provides the benefit based on the new brackets, then the benefit comes from the bracket changes and not from the table update.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  There needed to be an update.  The question is whether the tables were calculated "the same way".  I can imagine there is some adjustment for other income you might have.  One could make that adjustment larger to bring more money into the government sooner or smaller to leave more money in paychecks.  The claim is that adjustment was made smaller this year, which is supported by the fact that refunds are smaller.  I haven't done the calculation to figure it out, and it is the sort of charge people like to make.

Comment: @BenVoigt "the tables were adjusted to lower the withholding"  Nothing about this suggests a new approach.  Your statement "just with different tax rates and different standard deductions" is completely consistent with this.

Comment: @RossMillikan: That is not supported by smaller refunds, which can also be explained by (1) fewer people itemizing and (2) people who do itemize having SALT capped at $10k.  That is, smaller refunds are *consistent* with a change in methodology of the type you describe, but not evidence for it.

Comment: @JimmyJames: But Ross's answer *is* claiming a new methodology, as his comment confirms.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't see that in his answer or in the comment.  Regardless, a new methodology is not required to lower the withholding.  The 'methodology' aspect is just a strawman.

Comment: @BenVoigt I read articles (e.g. https://home.treasury.gov/news/press-releases/sm0249) that included quotes from the head of the treasury, indicating that they do indeed have the ability to apply some judgement to the design of the tax tables. And that they designed them last year to try to account for the people who wouldn't update their W-4. That is, the tables had less withheld than they might have otherwise. Thus leading to larger after-withholding paychecks last year and smaller refunds this filing season.

Answer (score 2):

Refunds are caused by withholding calculations being larger than actual tax owed, and one the biggest reasons for that happening  is having income that changes throughout the year. It is the high *change* in income that causes the refund, not the income itself. A change in income can happen through hourly rate or number of hours worked changing. Your most recent job had an hourly rate change of $2, which caused a slight over-withholding. But the previous year, you went from having no income at all to having $10/hr, which was a much larger jump, so the refund was larger.

Comment: Good perspective. The tax owed is a *convex* function of income in a progressive scheme, so the "tax on the average" (what's owed) is less than the "average of the taxes" (what's withheld) when there is variation during the year -- the more so the larger the variation.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving less because last year tax witholdings were recalculated to be less than in previous years, in order to give the impression that your paychecks were larger.  In fact, you most likely don't owe any less tax at the end of this year, so that the refund you could have expected in previous years is less than it would have been then.  A nasty surprise if you forget that a refund is not an entitlement, but a function of how much you pay to begin with.  You are far from the only person in your situation, if you read the current news.. (not that it's much of a consolation)

Comment: Your "In fact," statement is false for most middle-class tax payers. The combination of the change in the base rates _and_ the doubling of the standard deductions means that most people paying taxes will see a real reduction in the total amount of taxes paid. (I know I did, and I know many others as well.)